# Want to fetch product count and random product image for each category. Below query works fine but performance is slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below query fetches category id, title, product count and random product image. I want to modify the below query to improve its performance. Below query takes 420ms to execute.

```sql
SELECT category_ID,
       category_Name,
       ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1
                      product_image1
               FROM tbl_products
               WHERE product_image1 <> ''
                 AND product_isActive = 1
                 AND product_ID IN (SELECT refPrdCat_prdID
                                    FROM tbl_refPrdCatLink
                                    WHERE refPrdCat_catID = category_ID)
               ORDER BY NEWID()),
              '') AS Product_Image,
       ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(1)
               FROM tbl_products
               WHERE product_isActive = 1
                 AND product_ID IN (SELECT refPrdCat_prdID
                                    FROM tbl_refPrdCatLink
                                    WHERE refPrdCat_catID = category_ID)),
              '') AS countPrd
FROM tbl_category;
```

Comment: 420ms isn't particularly slow, however, one suggestion would be to move to joins, rather than subqueries with subqueries in the `SELECT` (which can be quite slow).

Answer (score 0):

I found product_image1 <> '' not necessary,since outside you are using isnull,also i see you are using the same query inside that's why i used cte. Not sure if it needs some changes,try running it,and please inform me!

```
 with cte_table (ref) as (
        select refPrdCat_prdID from tbl_refPrdCatLink where refPrdCat_catID =category_ID
    )
    select 
    category_ID,category_Name,
    isnull(
    select top 1 product_image1 from tbl_products where product_isActive=1 and  product_ID in (select * from cte_table) order by newID() ,'') Product_Image,
    isnull(
    select count(1) from tbl_products where product_isActive=1 and  product_ID in  (select * from cte_table) order by newID() ,'') countPrd
    )
    from tbl_category
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest rephrasing this as a lateral join and then using `exists` rather than `in`:

```
SELECT c.category_ID, c.category_Name, p.*
       COALESCE(p.Product_Image, '') as Product_Image,
       COALESCE(p.countPrd, 0) as countPrd
FROM tbl_category c CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) COUNT(*) OVER () as countPrd, Product_Image
      FROM tbl_products p
      WHERE p.product_isActive = 1 AND
            EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM tbl_refPrdCatLink pcl
                    WHERE pcl.refPrdCat_prdID = p.product_ID AND
                          pcl.refPrdCat_catID = c.category_ID
                   )
      ORDER BY (CASE WHEN product_image1 <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), NEWID()
     ) p;
```

This assumes that you have appropriate indexes on your tables -- to support the `JOIN`s.